# Как переписать на эмулятор Android файл?

Tags: android

Как переписать на эмулятор Android файл?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью отладочной консоли. Перейти в папку <android-sdk>/tools и выполнить команду.

```
./adb push file2copy /data/file2copy
```